# Библиотеки С++

Tags: c++

К какой библиотеке принадлежат функции atoi, itoa?

Comment: Кстати, я переписывал эти функции вручную, получилось в 5 раз быстрее.

Comment: Какой компилятор?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если быть точным, то эти функции лежат в libc (в Линуксе - glibc). Заголовки cstdlib (stdlib.h) содержат объявления этих функций, и поэтому их включение в код делает эти функции доступными.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Comment: У меня stdlib.

Comment: У Вас - это где?

Comment: в C++Builder 6.

Comment: Вообще-то в более современных компиляторах уже давно есть cstdlib, и он более рекомендован для С++. Это, кажется, еще С++98 определяет.

Comment: Это, наверное, так, тем более, что эти ф-ции в Билдере заменены на более удобные.